# Get parameter of shortcode in Insert PHP Code Snippet plugin using ACF repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, code-snippets, acfpro

Everybody hello! I'm sorry for asking such kind easy question, I'm pretty new at this. I have problem with transfering parameter value and echoing it to itself.

PHP code snippet on page:
`[xyz-ips snippet="Generating-content" paramSet="1"]`

Inside 'generating content':

```
<?php if( have_rows('information') ): ?>
   <?php while( have_rows('information') ): the_row(); ?>
      <?php $sub_value = get_sub_field('number'); 
         if($sub_value == 1): ?>
            <div class="d-block d-md-flex d-lg-flex">
               <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
                  <div>
                     <?php if( have_rows('repeatable_content') ): ?>
                        <?php while( have_rows('repeatable_content') ): the_row(); ?>
                           <p>
                              <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
                           </p>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Right now I need to change condition `if($sub_value == 1)` to `if($sub_value == "PARAMETER VALUE")`

Please help, guys!

Comment: which parameter you want to add in condition?

Comment: Hi, Arman! Parameter which is in xyz shortcode - paramSet="1"

Comment: check answer i already give your answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: First, can you try using 'paramset' instead of the uppercase attribute name, it can cause problems. If not working, can you share the code where you create your shortcode? Could be multiple reasons. Using `$atts['paramset']` is the way to go.

Comment: Please try to focus more your question and ignore /delete unnecessary code

Comment: You are asking to modify the shortcode `xyz-ips` whatever that is. Instead, you should build your own shortcode to execute your code.  (unless you already wrote the `xyz-ips` shortcode? )  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

Comment: Hey, Howard! I'm trying to modify my xyz plugin shortcode. Unfortunately, there's no way I can use my own shortcode in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping! The main issue of this problem is that you have to buy premium version of this plugin, your version is working in another plugins :)

Working plugin's name: **Shortcodes Blocks Creator Ultimate**

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are looking for.Not tested but it should work.

```
<?php
  $paramSet = (!isset($atts['paramSet'])) ? $atts['paramSet'] : 'default';
 if (have_rows('information')) : ?>
<?php while (have_rows('information')) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php $sub_value = get_sub_field('number');
    if ($sub_value == $paramSet) : ?>
        <div class="d-block d-md-flex d-lg-flex">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
            <div>
                <?php if (have_rows('repeatable_content')) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_rows('repeatable_content')) : the_row(); ?>
                        <p>
                            <?php the_sub_field('text'); ?>
                        </p>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Read More - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Arman! I've tried that way, but unfortunately it doesn't output any value. $paramSet doesn't have any value this way...

Comment: also according to that link a comment mentions that parameters must be all lowercase. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/#comment-3820 So that means `$atts['paramSet']`might actually be just `$atts['paramset']`

Comment: [xyz-ips snippet="Generating-content" paramSet="1"] did you tried with exactly this? it should return value 1.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried exactly this shortcode, also tried uppercase and lowercase this values, still nothing...

Comment: How you are calling the shortcode please paste here